# ERROR 1045 (28000) & access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'

Tags: mysql, installation, ubuntu, password

**UBUNTU 22.04.1, mysql ver 8.0.30**

### (1)

I get `sudo apt install mysql-server` then

`sudo mysql_secure_installation`

Get in loop this error for each complicated passwords I tried: (contained: `'<>&(*Pp1'`) returns↓

> Failed! Error: SET PASSWORD has no significance for user
> ‘root’@’localhost’ as the authentication method used doesn’t store
> authentication data in the MySQL server. Please consider using ALTER
> USER instead if you want to change authentication parameters.

### (2)

Then try:

- `sudo mysql`
- `alter user 'root'@'localhost' identified with mysql_native_password by 'password';`

### (3)

Now ever returns:

> error access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
> error 1045 (28000): access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using
> password: yes)

### (4)

Then try

- `sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql*`
- `sudo apt-get purge mysql*`
- `sudo apt-get autoremove`
- `sudo apt-get autoclean`
- `sudo apt-get remove dbconfig-mysql`
- `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`
- `sudo apt-get install mysql-server`

### (5)

Now ever shows:

> ERROR 1045 (28000)

or

> access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'

---

I can not refresh mysql with reinstall.

How can I retrieve the mysql and start step **(1)** newly cleaned from pre password configurations?

Answer (score 4):

**ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)**

1. `sudo dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server-8.0`

( use `sudo dpkg --get-selections | grep sql` to get your version)

**completely remove MySQLconfig and data?**

2. `sudo rm -r /var/lib/mysql`

(Users and passwords (including the root password) are stored in the database itself, and the default data dir is `/var/lib/mysql`.)

- [Ref1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21944936/error-1045-28000-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-using-password-y)
- [Ref2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1018312/how-can-i-completely-remove-mysql-including-config-and-data)